# how to use Collection.find() inside route action of Meteor js

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a peice of code;

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'master_layout'
});


Router.map(function(){

    this.route('generatePDF', {
    path: '/pdf',
    where: 'server',
    action: function() {

        console.log(voters.findOne().fetch());
        var voters = voters.find();

    ....
    }
});
```

How can I use any given collection inside **action** of routes.

i get error as below;

```
W20160510-20:19:29.909(5.5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined
W20160510-20:19:29.910(5.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].action (lib/routes.js:40:29)
W20160510-20:19:29.910(5.5)? (STDERR)     at boundNext (packages/iron_middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
action: function () {
    this.render('someTemplate',{
        data: function(){
            return Voters.find()
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple errors in your code.

Firstly, `voters` is `undefined` in the `console.log` line (as your error log says).
Secondly, `Voters.findOne()` returns a single document (assuming you have a collection called `Voters`). You can't call `fetch` on a document.
You can call `fetch` on a cursor. For example, `Voters.find().fetch()` would be fine.

Hope that helps

Comment: It also looks like you're just starting out with Meteor. The recommended router to use is `kadia:flowrouter`, not `iron:router`.